# Zurb Foundation Abide Add custom checking rule

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, zurb-foundation, abide

I am using Zurb Foundation abide for my form checking. But I am confused of how to add the rule of checking for my personal form input.

For example I have two fields that need to be checked if they are equal.

```
<form id="myForm">

<input name="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
<input name="pwd2" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password again">

</form>
```

If they are equal, the form will process to the next step.
Else it shows the error message of 'The password must be the same'

Big thanks

Comment: Unless your question has something to do with the jQuery Validate plugin, do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag.

Comment: The zurb foundation abide is using the jQuery for the form checking, i just wanna know is it possible to override that function and make a little correction.

Comment: And tagging questions with things that have nothing to do with its content is highly discouraged.  It's called tag-spamming.   If you're not sure then read [the tag-wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate)

Answer (score 1):

You can use abide's Equal To helper, http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html#equal-to

```
<form id="myForm">

<input id="pwd" name="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
<input id="pwd2" data-equalto="pwd" name="pwd2" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password again">

</form>
```